# How to insert a string to a text field programatically in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to add a string of text to a text field using JavaScript but I don't want to use the `onClick` or `onLoad` events to do so.

I simply want the JavaScript to be executed as soon as the browser reads it and the JavaScript will be within the body of the html.

The text field is something like:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formname" id="user-registration-form">
    <input type="text" name="edit-form" id="edit-form" />
</form>
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> edit-form.value="the new value"; </script>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

did you try getting this by `document.getElementById()`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("edit-mail").value="the new value"; </script>
```

assuming *edit-mail* is your textbox id

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.formname.edit-mail.value="the new value";
</script>
```

Comment: I've tweaked the answer for what I presume was a typo. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("edit-mail").value="he new value"
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the time you don't have the luxury of all the form elements having ids.  This is how you can make it work with the field only having a name attribute:

```
document.getElementById('user-registration-form').elements['edit-form'].value = 'new value';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var textfield = document.getElementByName("x");
textfield.value = "My text";
```

or directly d`ocument.getElementByName("x").value = "My text";`

Instead of using getElementByName you can use getElementById if you want to get your element depending of its id instead of its name.